# How can I use Mongoid finder, which accept as an argument an array of items and search for records whose values are in the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

How can I use Mongoid finder, which accept as an argument an array of items and search for records whose values ​​are in the array.
Equivalent

```
Model.where(:id => [1,2,3,4,5])
```

with ActiveRecord. I note that a similar call in Mongoid does not bring the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Model.where(:id.in => [1,2,3,4,5])
```